# how to execute pl/sql procedure

Tags: plsql, procedure

**Procedure:**

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE ADDITION 
(
  A IN NUMBER  
, B IN NUMBER  
, C OUT number
) AS 
BEGIN
  C := A+B;
  dbms_output.put_line(c);
END ADDITION;
```

**executing:**

```
begin
 addition(4,5);
end;
```

**Error:**

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADDITION'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

How to rectify this error.Let me know what is the wrong in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure expects an `out` parameter which you also need to provide:

```
declare
 add_result number;
begin
 addition(4,5,add_result);
end;
/
```

Comment: error:-->PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.ADDITION is invalid
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @user3021349: then you are not telling us everything, because that certainly works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2860e/2

Comment: I here like `variable n number
 addition(4,5,:n);
 print n;` but some thing wrong in that.can u rectify this

Comment: @user3021349: sqlfiddle doesn't support DBMS_OUTPUT, but as you can see there is no error. So suddenly you have a "variable" `:n`. Where did that come from? Why didn't you include that information in your original question? Which SQL client (tool) do you use to run those statements?

Comment: But i tried what is your answer in sql developer,I'm getting error.why?

Comment: @user3021349: I have no idea what you are doing. I tested the code in my answer in SQL Developer before I posted it - it works fine for me.

Comment: ya working u answer fine.but also we can also use this method also. 
`variable c number;
execute addition (4,5,:c);
print c;`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name ya working your answer perfectly.i have one more doubt can u clear that please